# How to find all coupling bracket with regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to have one regular expression to find all curly brackets and replace them with other strings.

For example, I want to replace "**{foo}**" with "**FOO**" and "**{bar}**" with "**BAR**" and "**{}**" with "**EMPTY**". If the input is "**abc {foo} def {bar} {}**", then the output is "**abc FOO def BAR EMPTY**".

Nested brackets or un-coupled brackets are not allowed. If character "{" or "}" is necessary. It should be doubled. So, "{{ def }}" is just "{ def }".

Other string in {} is not allowed. Say, I just want "**{foo}**" and "**{bar}**". So, "**abc {xyz} def**" should be recognized as invalid input.

Comment: Are you using sed? Perl? Java? Python? Something else?

Comment: C#, but I don't think it matters much.

Comment: Almost all regex implementations differ is some respect. If you'd be using JavaScript for example, you couldn't have used `Dav`'s 1st suggestion. If you were using Perl, then the capitalization could be done in one go. So yes, it *does* matter.

Answer (score 3):

If you have negative lookbehinds/lookaheads available:

```
(?<!{){([a-z]+)}(?!})
```

and replace with the value of the matching group.

The `([a-z]+)` matches your contained character string, the `(?<!{)` makes sure there isn't a second `{` before your `{`, and the `(?!})` makes sure there isn't a second `}` after your `}`.

If you don't have lookbehinds/lookaheads, then

```
(?^|[^{]){([a-z]+)}(?$|[^})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first go and replace `{}` with `EMPTY` without using a regular expression.

Then use

```
(?<!{){(foo|bar)}(?!})
```

to match `{foo}` or `{bar}` but not `{}` or `{{anything}}` or `{anything}`

Backreference no. 1 contains the matched text.

So a code snippet could look like

```
Regex matches = new Regex(@"(?<!\{)\{(foo|bar)\}(?!\})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
resultString = matches.Replace(subjectString, "$1".ToUpper());
```

(I hope that calling ToUpper() on a string works; I don't know C#, so please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with C# myself, but I'm almost certain that first the string literal `"$1"` gets capitalized (and nothing gets changed) and after that operation, it is used as a regex-replacement string.